# Property 'base64Data' does not exist on type 'CameraPhoto' in Ionic4 using capacitor

Tags: ionic4, capacitor

I was following a tutorial where for uploading a picture from native application they choose resultType as CameraResultType.Base64 and then got the base64Data from that image and finally convert that to filestream. But in my case base64Data this property was not available. I want to know what is wrong with my code. Here is my code snippet:

```
import {Plugins, Capacitor, CameraSource, CameraResultType} from '@capacitor/core';

Plugins.Camera.getPhoto({
      quality: 50,
      source: CameraSource.Prompt,
      correctOrientation: true,
      height: 320,
      width: 320,
      resultType: CameraResultType.Base64
    }).then(image => {
      this.selectedImage = image.base64Data;
    }).catch(err =>{
      console.log(err);
    });
```

I need to upload the image as file stream. Is there any other way to get the filestream from the taken image or webpath? If anyone know the work around please let me know. I already ran 'ionic capacitor update' command to make sure my capacitor is up-to-date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are following an out of date tutorial, base64Data was removed before the final release.

You can use base64String instead, but note that `base64String` is just the base64 representation of the image, if you want a data url that can be used as a img src you should use `CameraResultType. DataUrl` and `image.dataUrl`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Could you please tell me how can I get a File out of dataurl as I need to upload the image as a file. It would be a great help for me sir.